# M2.4.2 - XML the footer HTML markup not coming altogether any clue?

Tags: magento2, xml

Developing a new frontend using BS5, the issue with the layout XML keeps breaking, the footer HTML markup not coming altogether any clue?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

        <!-- Header -->
        <referenceContainer name="header.container" htmlClass="header">
            <!-- Header Content -->
            <container name="header.content" htmlClass="content" htmlTag="div" />
        </referenceContainer>
        <!-- <referenceContainer name="header.content" htmlClass="content" /> -->

        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">top-links</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>

        <referenceContainer name="page.top">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="html/topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>

        <!-- Main -->
        <referenceContainer name="main.content"/>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <referenceContainer name="footer.container" htmlClass="footer">
            <!-- Footer Content -->
            <container name="footer.content" htmlClass="content my-3" htmlTag="div">
                <container name="footer.row" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="row">
                    <container name="footer.newsletter" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 order-md-2" />
                    <container name="footer.navigation" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-9 order-md-1">
                        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer_navigation</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                    </container>
                </container>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>

        <!-- Removing Magento Native Blocks -->
        <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="currency" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel.wrapper" remove="true" />

        <!-- Moving Elements to the new Containers -->
        <move element="logo" destination="header.content" before="-" />
        <move element="minicart" destination="header.content" after="logo" />
        <move element="top.search" destination="header.content" after="minicart" />
        <move element="top.links" destination="header.content" after="-" />
        <!-- <move element="footer_links" destination="footer-links-container" /> -->
        <move element="form.subscribe" destination="footer.newsletter" />
        <!-- <move element="store_switcher" destination="footer-tools-container" /> -->
        <move element="copyright" destination="footer.content" after="-"/>
        <!-- <move element="report.bugs" destination="footer-legal-container" /> -->

    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: It seems the footer comes back if I change the name from "footer.container" to "footer-container", any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the issue, is basically I am using **referenceContainer** tag which is by definition a reference to an existing container, and since I have not created the container in the first place, it was not matching therefore it never been rendered.

I have figured that I must define the container in the page_layout, and in my case, it was **page_layout/1column.xml**

I hope this helps anyone who might have a similar issue.